# C: printf a float value

Tags: c, floating-point

I want to print a float value which has 2 integer digits and 6 decimal digits after the comma. If I just use `printf("%f", myFloat)` I'm getting a truncated value.

I don't know if this always happens in C, or it's just because I'm using C for microcontrollers (CCS to be exact), but at the reference it tells that `%f` get just that: a truncated float.

If my float is `44.556677`, I'm printing out `"44.55"`, only the first two decimal digits.

So the question is... how can I print my 6 digits (and just the six of them, just in case I'm having zeros after that or something)?

Comment: `%2.6f` sounds like the correct format string, if your runtime library supports it.

Comment: If you are using `float` then you won't get 8 meaningful significant decimal digits in any case. You are asking for more precision than the data type posesses. The nearest float to `44.556677` is [44.55667 87719 72656 25](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=44.556677)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How many meaningful digits are there?

Comment: Now is an appropriate time to bring up "Floating Point Numbers Aren't Real": http://www.freshsources.com/FPNotReal.pdf

Comment: @roman for single precision it's around 7 sig digits

Comment: Your title doesn't match your content well. Your content asks for 6 decimal places, but your title doesn't say anything about that

Comment: @barlop Six years later, I think I'll live with it man

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
printf("%.6f", myFloat);
```

6 represents the number of digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks! I though of it, but I just thought It couldn't be so easy!

Comment: The `2` does not mean the number of digits before the decimal point, it means the minimum *total* field width (which will already be greater than 2), so here it does nothing.

Answer (score 37):

`printf("%9.6f", myFloat)` specifies a format with 9 total characters: 2 digits before the dot, the dot itself, and six digits after the dot.

Comment: `%09.6f` might also be an option.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight with `printf("%9.6f", myFloat)` , if I give 3 digit before dot then it still print the 3 digits before dot. can you please explain why so ?

Comment: And one of the website https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output explaining ` %3.2f ` as (print as a floating point at least 3 wide and a precision of 2) .
So I am confuse now

Comment: @xyz In C's `printf` a `%N`, where `N` is a number, always defines the overall *minimum* width of the *complete* output of a field.  `%6s` always prints 6 characters, at least (more if the string is longer).  Shorter outputs will be filled (in that case at the left side, use `-N` to fill on the right).  There is *no exception for floats*.  `%3f` prints at least 3 characters, so `1.0` is output as `__1` (two leading spaces shown as `_`) where `1.1` is output as `1.1` with no filling, it already has 3 characters.  Hence in `%N.Mf` there are, at least, `N-M-1` characters of room before the dot.

Answer (score 10):

```
printf("%.<number>f", myFloat) //where <number> - digit after comma
```

https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: be carefull! the **f** specifier have to be after the number of digits so `printf("%.numberf", myFloat)`
Tank you for the useful link!

Answer (score 9):

```
printf("%0k.yf" float_variable_name)
```

Here `k` is the total number of characters you want to get printed. `k = x + 1 + y` (`+ 1` for the dot) and `float_variable_name` is the float variable that you want to get printed.

Suppose you want to print x digits before the decimal point and y digits after it. Now, if the number of digits before float_variable_name is less than x, then it will automatically prepend that many zeroes before it.

Answer (score 5):

Try these to clarify the issue of right alignment in float point printing

```
printf(" 4|%4.1lf\n", 8.9);
printf("04|%04.1lf\n", 8.9);
```

the output is

```
 4| 8.9
04|08.9
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `%.6f`.
This will print 6 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%2.6f` instead of `%f` in your printf statement

Comment: It isn't correct. Format "%2.6f" means total width of 2 characters with 6 characters after decimal point.

Comment: @ValeriyVan This is a bit like nitpicking, but I think it is important: **The `2` is not wrong here**, but it is highly superfluous (not even redundant) which usually tells us, that the writer is confused on how printf works.  `%2.6f` means "at least 2 characters wide with 6 digits after the dot".  As we will always see at least 8 characters, the 2 is far too low to have any effect here and it needs to be `9` or above to create some effect. Note that **we do not talk Math** here: In `%+9.6f` the `9` still is not needed, as `%+.6f` always has a width of at least 9: sign, digit, dot, 6 digits

Comment: @Tino I was thinking %0.3f would print 0 digits in total - that also doesn't make sense :D