# Converting inches to centrimetres

Tags: c

I've wrote this simple program which converts inches to centimetres but the float gives me some huge numbers after the decimal place. I want it to look more like for example 25.78 rather than 25.780000 or something. What should I change to make it look like that? Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float inches, centimeters;

    printf("Enter a number of inches to be converted: ");
    scanf(" %f", &inches);

    centimeters = inches * 2.54;        // 1 inch = 2.54cm

    printf("%f is equalled to %fcm\n",inches, centimeters);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%.2f` rather than `%f` in the printf statement will do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: printf a float value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345581/c-printf-a-float-value)

Comment: More info about formating strings in C: http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output

Comment: try `%g` instead of `%f`.

Comment: @user2938819 - There are several good answers below.  if you see one that works for you, acknowledge it by clicking the hollow check mark or an up arrow.

Answer (score 2):

Use `%.2f` in your `printf`.

```
printf("%.2f is equalled to %.2fcm\n",inches, centimeters);
```

and must read [Basics of Formatted Input/Output in C](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/c_io.html).

Answer (score 2):

Add a precision to your format specifier in printf:

```
printf("%.2f is equalled to %.2f cm\n", inches, centimeters);
```

`%.2f` means your value will have a precision of 2 places after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

Change the format a bit - instead of using `"%f"` use `".2%f`.

Like

```
//-------vv------ and -------vv-----------------------------
printf("%.2f is equalled to %.2fcm\n",inches, centimeters);
//-------^^------------------^^-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

printf("%.2f", myFloat); 2 represents number of digits after decimal point

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%f is equalled to %.2fcm\n",inches, centimeters);
```

Note the extra  %.2f

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%f is equalled to %.2fcm\n",inches, centimeters);`

U can write %.2f if u need the precision to be 2.

Read these articles:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/c_io.html