# What is the easiest way to only display decimals for the float 25.50 in C?

Tags: c

Just starting out C. For instance given the number float $25.50. I want to display the dollars and cents separately. So for dollars I can use %.0f to display 25. How can I only display the 50?

Comment: Please show us your entire code with current output and expected output

Comment: `cents = money - floor(money)`?

Comment: would `printf(%2.2f, value)` work?

Comment: How do you want to handle negative numbers (or do you at all)? Also, you're probably setting yourself up for some pain using floating point arithmetic with amounts of money (because floating point arithmetic is imprecise). Consider using an `int` or `long` that contains the amount in cents instead of a float that contains it in dollars.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345581/c-printf-a-float-value -- I don't have access to a C compiler at the moment so I can't test if you can have `printf()` truncate numbers before the decimal point though.

Comment: Try `man modf` for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round to the nearest cent.
Break into whole and fractional parts.
Print

```
 float amount = 25.50;

 amount = roundf(amount*100.0f)/100.0f;
 float dollars, cents;
 cents = modff(amount, &dollars);
 printf("%.0f Dollars  %.0f Cents\n", dollars, cents*100);
```

Rounding is important to deal with amounts like 1.996 printing as "1 Dollars 100 cents".

`modf()` nicely separates the fraction from the whole number parts of a floating point number .
Use `modf()` for `double`.

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28114599/2410359) is on the money about using `double` vs. `float` concerning currency.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for `modf()` from `<math.h>`.  That will split the value into the integer part and the fractional part.

```
double amount = 25.50;
double dollars;
double cents = modf(amount, &dollars);
```

You can then print just the fraction:

```
printf("%.2f", cents);
```

or, if you're not going to need the fractional value again:

```
printf("%.2f", modf(amount, &dollars));
```

There isn't a way using just `printf()` to print only the fractional part of a number; you have to modify the value passed to it for printing so that it only sees the fractional part.

(*Note that you should round the value before splitting it, as shown by [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28114592/15168).*)

For many plausible money values, you could probably use `cents = amount - (int64_t)amount` or something similar — but the better way to do it is with `modf()`.

(*Beware: there's also the `fmod()` function for calculating the modulus of two double values, the floating point analogue of the `%` operator.*)

Also, do not use `float` for real monetary calculations — at least, not accounting style calculations.  You can more or less represent values up to $99,999.99 reliably to 2 decimal places, but anything much beyond that is unreliable.  (In one casual test, adding `0.01` to `262144.00` didn't change the result.)  If you must use floating point numbers, then use `double`.

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with money with numbers, even if it's just the background of your fun, you really shouldn't have any floating point data type involved. You should use all integers. Not even mention the unreasonability of using `float` to represent it.

For example:

```
struct money 
{ 
    long dollars, cents;
}
```

but normally, money is handled directly from the minimal unit:

```
typedef money long;
```

and represent money from `cents`. When you want dollars:

```
long dollar_part(money m)
{
    return m / 100;
}
```

cents:

```
long cent_part(money m)
{
    return m % 100;
}
```

so:

```
money cash;
/* ... */
printf("$ld dollars, $2ld cents", dollar_part(cash), cent_part(cash));
```

Comment: Avoiding fp works fine for additional/subtraction, But how would one code  the [monthly payment on a mortgage formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_loan#Capital_and_interest)?

Comment: There are also things like unit costs, where perhaps washers are $1.00 per thousand, so the unit price is $0.001. That is, you sometimes you need smaller units than cents. That's not to deny your basic thesis (floating point in general, `float` in particular, is unsuitable for monetary calculations). Ideally, you'd be able to use the 128-bit decimal floating point defined in IEEE 754:2008, and implemented on IBM Power systems. See [General Decimal Arithmetic](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/) for a treasure trove of information on both binary and decimal floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score -1):

Once you use the mod operator and get the 25, just subtract that value from the original to get the remaining cent value as a float. Multiply by 100 to get the decimal.

Example: `25.50`

Methodology:

1. Get the first part of the number (i.e. `25`)
2. `25.50-25 = .50`
3. `.50 * 100 = 50` -> store in variable for later display

Comment: Why would you use the mod operator here?

Comment: The `%.0f` mentioned in the question is used for output formatting. It's not the modulo operator.