# Meaning of the number between % and . in printf("%5.2f", 123456.987654)

Tags: c, printf

What is the meaning of the number between % and . in `printf`? Both the `printf`'s below print the same number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double r = 123456.987654;
    printf("%1.2f\n", r);   // 123456.99
    printf("%5.2f\n", r);   // 123456.99
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C: printf a float value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345581/c-printf-a-float-value). (Especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345663/452102)

Comment: Did you read [the manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)? Try a larger number (`20`?) to see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) the number between `%` and optional `.` character in a `printf` format specifier is:

> (optional) integer value or * that specifies minimum field width. The result is padded with space characters (by default), if required, on the left when right-justified, or on the right if left-justified. In the case when * is used, the width is specified by an additional argument of type int. If the value of the argument is negative, it results with the - flag specified and positive field width. (Note: This is the minimum width: The value is never truncated.)

It specifies *minimum* field width. If the result to be printed would have less characters than minimum field width, it would have been padded with spaces. Because the resulting string `"123456.99"` has 9 characters, specifying field width that is lower or equal to `9` is going to make no difference.

Comment: i wrote printf("%5f\n", 254.3); and the output is 254.300000. I expected 254.3 because 254.3 is composed by 5 chacarters. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345581/c-printf-a-float-value/8345663#8345663 it should display 5 characters.

Comment: `I expected 254.3` default precision is 6. If you want one precision (ie. one digit after the comma), specify it. `because 254.3 is composed by 5 chacarters.` that's strange assumption. As said, the number specifies __minimum__ field width. The value is never truncated.

Comment: @FedericaGuidotti "I expected 254.3 because 254.3 is composed by 5 chacarters." --> `double` can encode about 2^64 different values exactly.  254.3 is not one of them.  Instead a nearby value was used which when written fully in decimal is more like "254.30000000000001136..."  Printing that with `"%5f"` rounds to 254.300000.